# Extracting clock hands from an image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am currently working on an application to extract the time from an image of an analog clock. I am having a problem in extracting the hands from the image.

I am currently using a Hough Circle to extract the clock face, then preforming a canny edge detection and dialating the image. Then finally a Hough Line transform to extract the hands. However, the Hough Line tranform also detects some erronous lines on the edge of the clock and numbers ect along with the clock hands.

To fix this i tried, getting the center of the clock and checking if that point lies on the line that was detected, as the hands of the clock always pass through the center. However, the Hough Lines are not always 100% accurate and neither is the center point so not all of them pass through the center. Is there anyway to see if a line passes close to a point?

Here is an example image:

[image]

As can be seen the Hough transform did originally detect the lines, but they did not perfectly pass through the origin. So they were discarded.

Comment: You can probably make the clock hands contain the center point by dilating them with a simple circle kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the distance separating a point from a line with the formula given here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line.

The formula itself is a bit complicated (that's why I only posted the link), but if you have the coordinates of your lines, you should be able to use it.

If you call `A` the center point, the exact definition of this distance is `the distance between A and the point of the line that is the closest to A`. i guess you can then use a threshold to filter out lines that are too far away from the center. beware though, if your line is a segment that is aligned with the center but does not pass through it (if it's a number far away from the center for instance), the threshold method will still yield it.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try this. It is pretty close to what i was concidering which was a flat distance from the centre.

Comment: this seems to have worked with extracting the lines.

Comment: Great :) Happy to have helped